# Append string to column on command line

Tags: linux, command-line, paste

I have a 3 column file.  I would like to append a third column which is just one word repeated many times.  I tried the following

```
paste file.tsv <(echo 'new_text') > new_file.tsv
```

But the text 'new_text' only appears on the first line, not every line.

How can I get 'new_text' to appear on every line.

Thanks

Comment: "I have a 3 column file. I would like to append a third column" - do you mean a 4th one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '1,$ s/$/;ABC/' infile > outfile
```

This replaces the line end ("$") with ";ABC".